Detect ticks and circles in images using OpenCV
I wrote some code to process images (yes or no).
Currently I first compare the images against templates:

a template of a no (check if no is not circled)
a template of a yes (to check if yes is not circled)
a template of a no checkbox (unchecked)
a template of a yes checkbox (unchecked)
templates of yes/no checked digitally
templates of yes/no checked by hand

If I have an image circled (by hand) I use OpenCV to detect circles using this code: circle detection
But it does not really detect shapes around the no/yes. I see random circles being detected, if I plot for debugging purposes the circles
im turns this increases false positives

I tried changing the min max radius in the houghCircle function to account for this (sometimes the O of the NO is mistaken for a circle)

I also tried to use OpenCV to detect a X or V shape in the image to emulate a tickbox, using this tick detection
def detect_text_circle(image_gray, text_bbox=None, show_plots=False):
    """
    Detects if the text is surrounded by a circle.
    """
    if text_bbox is not None:
        x_text, y_text, w_text, h_text = text_bbox
        roi = image_gray[y_text - 10 : y_text + h_text + 10, x_text - 10 : x_text + w_text + 10]
    else:
        roi = image_gray

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, (9, 9), 0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
        blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.2, minDist=20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=15, maxRadius=500
    )

    confidence = 0
    detected = False

    if circles is not None:
        detected = True
        confidence = 80  # Assign a confidence value based on detection

        LOGGER.debug(f"Circles detected: {len(circles[0])}")

        if show_plots:
            output = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            for circle in circles[0, :]:
                cx, cy, radius = map(int, circle)
                LOGGER.debug(f"Circles detected with centre at {(cx, cy,)} and radius {radius}")
                cv2.circle(output, (cx, cy), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            plt.imshow(output)
            plt.title("Detected Circles Around Text")
            plt.axis("off")
            plt.show()
    else:

        LOGGER.debug("No circles detected around text.")

    return detected, confidence


def detect_tick_marks(checkbox_roi, show_plots=False):
    """
    Detects tick marks within a checkbox region by analyzing lines
    and checking for V or X shapes.

    Parameters:
        checkbox_roi (numpy.ndarray): Grayscale image of the checkbox region.
        show_plots (bool): If True, displays plots of detected lines.

    Returns:
        detected (bool): True if a tick mark is detected.
        confidence (float): Confidence value between 0 and 100.
    """
    # Preprocess ROI for edge detection
    roi_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(checkbox_roi, (3, 3), 0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(roi_blur, threshold1=50, threshold2=150, apertureSize=3)

    # Apply Hough Line Transform
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=20, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=5)

    confidence = 0
    detected = False

    if lines is not None and len(lines) > 0:

        LOGGER.debug(f"Lines detected in checkbox: {len(lines)}")

        # Analyze pairs of lines to detect V or X shapes
        combinations = list(itertools.combinations(lines, 2))
        shape_detected = False
        for idx, (line1, line2) in enumerate(combinations):
            x1_1, y1_1, x2_1, y2_1 = line1[0]
            x1_2, y1_2, x2_2, y2_2 = line2[0]

            # Calculate angles of the lines
            angle1 = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y2_1 - y1_1, x2_1 - x1_1))
            angle2 = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y2_2 - y1_2, x2_2 - x1_2))
            angle_between = abs(angle1 - angle2)
            if angle_between > 180:
                angle_between = 360 - angle_between

            # Calculate lengths of the lines
            length1 = np.hypot(x2_1 - x1_1, y2_1 - y1_1)
            length2 = np.hypot(x2_2 - x1_2, y2_2 - y1_2)

            # Check if lines intersect
            def lines_intersect(p1, p2, p3, p4):
                """Check if line segments (p1-p2) and (p3-p4) intersect."""
                s1_x = p2[0] - p1[0]
                s1_y = p2[1] - p1[1]
                s2_x = p4[0] - p3[0]
                s2_y = p4[1] - p3[1]

                denominator = -s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y
                if denominator == 0:
                    return False  # Lines are parallel

                s = (-s1_y * (p1[0] - p3[0]) + s1_x * (p1[1] - p3[1])) / denominator
                t = (s2_x * (p1[1] - p3[1]) - s2_y * (p1[0] - p3[0])) / denominator

                if (0 <= s <= 1) and (0 <= t <= 1):
                    return True
                return False

            intersects = lines_intersect((x1_1, y1_1), (x2_1, y2_1), (x1_2, y1_2), (x2_2, y2_2))

            if intersects:
                #
                LOGGER.debug(
                    f"Lines {idx} intersect at angle {angle_between:.2f} degrees with lengths {length1:.2f}, {length2:.2f}"
                )

                # Check for V shape (tick mark)
                if 20 <= angle_between <= 60:
                    # Further checks can be added for line lengths and positions
                    shape_detected = True
                    confidence = min(100, (100 - angle_between) + (min(length1, length2) * 2))
                    #
                    LOGGER.debug(f"V shape detected with confidence {confidence:.2f}")
                    break

                # Check for X shape (cross mark)
                elif 80 <= angle_between <= 100:
                    shape_detected = True
                    confidence = min(90, (angle_between) + (min(length1, length2) * 2))
                    #
                    LOGGER.debug(f"X shape detected with confidence {confidence:.2f}")
                    break

        if not shape_detected:
            # If no V or X shape detected, but lines are present
            confidence = 50  # Lower confidence
            #
            LOGGER.debug("Lines detected but no V or X shape formed.")

        detected = shape_detected

This also has a high false positive rate like the angles of the letter N or Y can be mistaken for a tick.
This part of the code looks at the image overall, I don't know how to limit the search of ticks only to the box.
wonder if anybody has experience and can suggest how to improve?
full code is here

Maybe better to include the specific code that you are having problems with in the question. Some example images would also be necessary.

you need a template and the annotated version. you need to align/register them. then you can tell what's new and what's old. -- DO NOT think thost scribbles are proper circles. hough will fail. it has to. do not use it for this. entirely wrong approach.

the picturr with a scribble around the No is a picture i would like the code to identify as circled.

thanks for bringing up the topic of tenplate matching, i am asking a different question. improving shape detenction (circles and ticks) when template fails

I did not suggest template matching (in the OpenCV sense). I suggested aligning the picture to a template of the form, so you can tell what has changed. that will involve a warp.

@bruvio Why do you need to identify it as a circle? Aren't you more concerned with whether there is a mark around the text, and not whether that mark is perfectly circular?

what is the way of finding a poligon that wraps the string?

classifying changes/marks as crosses/checks/circles should be left to ML, after you have identified the changed pixels on the form.

Use object detection deep learning models like yolo or use sift or find similar objects by matching features. hough transform is a bad good solution.
